# Нужно отредактрировать код C#

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, обработка-ошибок

Помогите, пожалуйста, отредактировать код так, что бы при введении y (yes) или n (no) выбивало "The price suits me", "The price doesn't suit me" и т.д. Просто я новичок

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{ 
       class TV
{
    public string model;
    public string company;
    public string country;
    public double price;
    public double weight;
    public double height;
    public double width;

    public TV() { }
    public TV(string model, string company, string country, double price, double weight, double height, double width)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.company = company;
        this.country = country;
        this.price = price;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }
}

    class Program : ProgramBase1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {

                Console.Write("Name of model: ");
                string sModel = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Name of Company: ");
                string sCompany = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Made in Country: ");
                string sCountry = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Price of TV: ");
                string sPrice = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Weight of TV: ");
                string sWeight = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Height of TV: ");
                string sHeight = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("The width of TV: ");
                string sWidth = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Does the price of the TV suit me? (y-yes, n-no): ");
                ConsoleKeyInfo keyprice = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Does the weight of the TV suit me? (y-yes, n-no): ");
                ConsoleKeyInfo keyweight = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Does the height of the TV suit me? (y-yes, n-no): : ");
                ConsoleKeyInfo keyheight = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Does the width of the TV suit me? (y-yes, n-no): : ");
                ConsoleKeyInfo keywidth = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();

                TV myTV = new TV();

                myTV.model = sModel;
                myTV.company = sCompany;
                myTV.country = sCountry;
                myTV.price = keyprice.Key == ConsoleKey.Y ? true : false; ;
                myTV.weight = keyweight.Key == ConsoleKey.Y ? true : false; ;
                myTV.height = keyheight.Key == ConsoleKey.Y ? true : false;
                myTV.width = keywidth.Key == ConsoleKey.Y ? true : false; ;

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("_________________________");
                Console.WriteLine("Does it match to what you want?");
                Console.WriteLine("_________________________");
                Console.WriteLine("Model: " + myTV.model);
                Console.WriteLine("Company: " + myTV.company);
                Console.WriteLine("Country: " + myTV.country);
                Console.WriteLine(myTV.price ? "The price suits me" :"The price doesn't suit me");
                Console.WriteLine(myTV.weight ? "The weight suits me" :"The weight doesn't suits me");
                Console.WriteLine(myTV.width ? "The width suits me" :"The width doesn't suit me");
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ничего не понятно, напишите как что работает и что как не работает

Comment: `if (keyprice.Key == ConsoleKey.Y) Console.WriteLine("The price suits me"); else Console.WriteLine("The price doesn't suit me");`

Comment: Спасибо! @aepot